# Python getting the date from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

hey i am currently just to get the data from the file

for example here a line from the file

```
Jan 10 09:32:07 j4-be03 sshd[3876]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.241.173.35  user=root
```

here the current code i am using but cant seem to achieve it when am spliting it

```
for line in myFile:
    list_of_line = line.split()
    date = list_of_line[0:3]
    print '\'',date,'\''
    if login_ctns.has_key(date):
        login_counts = login_ctns[date]
        login_counts = login_counts +1
        login_ctns[date] = login_counts
        #zero out the temporary counter as a precaution
        count_login =0
    else:
        login_ctns[date] = 1

print date
```

Comment: I don't see a question and no clue what your output should be like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is making `date` a list, which can't be used as a dict key.

Try:

```
date = ' '.join(list_of_line[0:3])
```

instead.